# Database details not getting displayed to in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Project is on Java Spring MVC using MySql.
Display not working (image attached below) as because maybe the function is not returning the query result or maybe something else is the cause.
The following is the function that is used to run query on database and return the result. This function is member of "User.java" file.

```
public List<User> getUsers()
{  
    return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from student",new RowMapper<User>()
            {  
                public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException 
                {  
                    User u = new User();  
                    u.setUserName(rs.getString(1));  
                    u.setPassword(rs.getString(2));  
                    u.setName(rs.getString(3));  
                    u.setBranch(rs.getString(4));
                    u.setM1(rs.getInt(5));
                    u.setM2(rs.getInt(6));
                    u.setM3(rs.getInt(7));
                    u.setAggregate(rs.getInt(8));
                    u.setGrade(rs.getString(9));
                    return u;  
                }  
            });  
}
```

This returns to "HomeController.java" and it's implementation is as follows..

```
@RequestMapping("/adminHome")  
public ModelAndView adminHome(User user){  
    List<User> list= user.getUsers();  
    return new ModelAndView("adminHome","list",list);  
}
```

and the corresponding JSP is "adminHome.jsp", shown below...

```
<body>
<h3>Hi ${name}</h3>
<h1>USERS List</h1>  
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">  
<tr><th>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>Name</th><th>Mobile</th>
<th>Branch</th><th>Marks1</th><th>Marks2</th><th>Marks3</th>
<th>Aggregate</th><th>Grade</th><th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th></tr>  
   <c:forEach var="u" items="${list}">   
   <tr>  
   <td>${u.username}</td>
   <td>${u.password}</td>   
   <td>${u.name}</td>  
   <td>${u.mobile}</td>  
   <td>${u.branch}</td>
   <td>${u.marks1}</td>
   <td>${u.marks2}</td>
   <td>${u.marks3}</td>
   <td>${u.aggregate}</td>
   <td>${u.grade}</td>   
   <td><a href="editemp/${u.username}">Edit</a></td>  
   <td><a href="deleteemp/${u.username}">Delete</a></td>  
   </tr>  
   </c:forEach>  
   </table>  
   <br/>  
   <a href="register">Add New User</a>     
</body>
```

[This is the final output and the list of users is not returning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TjB4.png)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String user(@Validated User user, Model model,Locale locale) 
{
    U = user.getUserName();
    String s1 = "password";
    String s2 = "name";
    String p = "X";
    try
    {
        final String selectQuery = "select * from student where username='"+U+"'";  
        Map<?, ?> map = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(selectQuery);
        Set set  = map.entrySet();
        Iterator itr=set.iterator();  

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {  
            //Converting to Map.Entry so that we can get key and value separately  
            Map.Entry entry=(Map.Entry)itr.next();  
            if(entry.getKey().equals(s1))
            {   
                p = entry.getValue().toString();
                System.out.println(p);
            }
            if(entry.getKey().equals(s2))
            {   
                NAME = entry.getValue().toString();
                System.out.println(p);
            }          
        }  
    }
    catch(Exception e2)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception Raised while Login(user)!!!");            //not inclusion of case of NULL return by username search in the sql query
    }

    String dest="user";
    if(user.getUserName().equals("admin") && user.getPassword().equals(p))
    {
        dest = "adminHome";
        System.out.println("Admin Page Requested");
        model.addAttribute("name", NAME);
    }
    else if(user.getUserName().equals(U) && user.getPassword().equals(p))
    {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested");
        model.addAttribute("name", NAME);
    }
    else
    {
        dest = "errLogin";                                                          //redirects to errLogin.jsp
        System.out.println("Err Login Page Requested, locale = " + locale);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Invalid login credentials !!! Try Again");                   
    }   
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: you want to show a list, but your mapper returns a single User ...

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: @Stultuske yes I want to show a list but my mapper is not returning anything, and yes I have debugged it.

Comment: extract your query from your mapper, and check if that actually returns a result.

Comment: getUsers() fucntion is not getting invoked

Comment: can you show us how you declare `user`, can you show us `HomeController` class?

Comment: so basically, this never runs? @RequestMapping("/adminHome")  
public ModelAndView adminHome(User user){

Comment: You are using `/user`url as per your screenshot and mapping in controller is `/adminHome`. Are you sure you are calling correct service?

Comment: @YCF_L `HomeController` is quite big and `user` is the delcared just as shown 'User user' in the function parameter.

Comment: What? `User` is your entity no?

Comment: @gohil90 from `/user` it uses `return "adminHome"`

Comment: It will go to adminHome.jsp and not to /adminHome mapping. You need to redirect it properly to another service. Can you add /user code here?

Comment: @gohil90 updated the `/user` code in the post, please refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not redirecting it correctly to `/adminHome` service. Instead, it is redirecting to `adminHome.jsp` page.

If you want to redirect it to `/adminHome` from `/user` service, instead of `return "adminHome";`, do the following -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String user(@Validated User user, Model model,Locale locale) {
    // your code and use return line as follows
    return "redirect:adminHome";
}
```

As you are using `String dest` for your final return statement, update that to `"redirect:<service_name>"`.

That should call your `/adminHome` service and everything should work fine.

Comment: Redirection is correct now, thanks, but now `return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from student",new RowMapper<User>()` is throwing Null Pointer Exception and page is crashing.

Comment: Check if your `jdbcTemplate` is configured properly or not with datasource. You would have to debug into it.